# LINQ not returning any results although they exist in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have the following two classes (simplified for clarity):

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string ReportPhase { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class DailyObservationReport : Report
{
    public int DayOfTraining { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfTraining { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

I've added them to the ApplicationDbContext as follows:
public DbSet Report { get; set; }

public

```
public DbSet<Amber.Models.ReportingModels.DailyObservationReport>DailyObservationReport { get; set; }
public DbSet<Amber.Models.ReportingModels.Rating> Rating { get; set; }
```

I have successfully created about 10 test reports in my table using a view, so I know there are records that should be returned in a LINQ query.  My understanding is that because I have the discriminator column, this LINQ query should return all DailyObservationReports in the context

```
var test2 = from r in _context.DailyObservationReport
                        select r;
```

however, it doesn't and neither does this one

```
var test = from r in _context.Report
                       where r.Discriminator.Equals("DailyObservationReport")
                       select r;
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I can't access the records in my database?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right connection string?

Comment: @DavidG I only have one connection string in this project and I'm able to insert records into the database using this controller, So I don't think it's a connection string issue

Comment: How sure are you? If you're not getting an exception, then this should work fine, which leaves the connection string as the most likely suspect.

Comment: @DavidG 99% sure.  I only have one connection string.  It's listed as the DefaultConnection in the appsettings.json file.  So unless I inadvertently overrode that connection string (not sure how I would have done that), I'm pretty certain it isn't the issue.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you have set up your context, could you show the startup code?

Comment: Simplification is fine, posting invalid model - not good. Take a look at posted `DailyObservationReport` class - it duplicates (shadows) the base `Report` class properties. Please provide more realistic model (and include the relevant fluent setup if any)

Comment: Those test reports that you created, were they `Report` or `DailyObservationReport`?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry about that.  Guess I'm a little frustrated and getting sloppy.  I've updated the models to provide a better picture of what I'm doing.  I haven't made any changes to the fluent setup but I can post some information if you let me know what you'd like to see.

Comment: @EvanHuang the test reports were all DailyObservationReport

Comment: No problem :) I've tried your updated model (EFC 2.0.1) and it works as expected. Both `_context.DailyObservationReport.ToList()` and `_context.Report.OfType<DailyObservationReport>().ToList()` execute something like `select ... from Report where Discriminator = 'DailyObservationReport'`.

Comment: set a breakpoint after the `_context` is created and examine its properties (in EF6 you'd look at _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString) - not sure what the right property in EFCore is.

Comment: `Discriminator` is not typically an actual property on your class. Rather, it's a column EF automatically adds to house the name of the derived type to support single-table inheritance. It also sounds as if you're manually creating the reports in the DB rather than via EF. More likely than not, there's some issue with either the column that is being considered the "discriminator" or the value you've set there is not actually correct. In either case, EF is simply finding no rows in the table that it can interpret as `DailyObservationReport` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your are still testing and possibly just verifying your queries in the debugger. If this is the case then it could just be due to the deferred execution of the IQueryable that makes it look like there are no results. Try this and see if `test2` or `test` are still empty.

```
var test2 = (from r in _context.DailyObservationReport
                        select r).ToArray();
```

or

```
var test = (from r in _context.Report
                       where r.Discriminator.Equals("DailyObservationReport")
                       select r).ToArray();
```